# Сохранение столбца матрицы в переменную

Tags: python, python-3.x, матрицы, numpy

Когда пытаюсь достать правую и левую колонки из матрицы

```
 import numpy as np
 def createSystem(pts2d,pts3d):    

pts2d = np.array[[1.0486, -0.3645], [-1.6851, -0.4004], [-0.9437, -0.42], [1.0682, 0.0699], [0.6077, -0.0771], [1.2543, -0.6454], [-0.2709, 0.8635], [-0.4571, -0.3645], [-0.7902, 0.0307], [0.7318, 0.6382], [-1.058, 0.3312], [0.3464, 0.3377], [0.3137, 0.1189], [-0.431, 0.0242], [-0.4799, 0.292], [0.6109, 0.083], [-0.4081, 0.292], [-0.1109, -0.2992], [0.5129, -0.0575], [0.1406, -0.4527]]
# ....ещё один массив
u = pts2d([:,1])
v = pts2d([:,2])
```

выводится ошибка:

```
    u = pts2d([:,1])
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Не стоит изменять вопрос после того, как предоставлен ответ. Это только запутывает остальных. Если появилась новая проблема, стоит оформить новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем коде есть сразу несколько ошибок.

1. `np.array` -- это функция, и нужно использовать круглые скобки, чтобы вызывать её:

   ```
   pts2d = np.array([[1.0486, -0.3645], [-1.6851, -0.4004], [-0.9437, -0.42], [1.0682, 0.0699], [0.6077, -0.0771], [1.2543, -0.6454], [-0.2709, 0.8635], [-0.4571, -0.3645], [-0.7902, 0.0307], [0.7318, 0.6382], [-1.058, 0.3312], [0.3464, 0.3377], [0.3137, 0.1189], [-0.431, 0.0242], [-0.4799, 0.292], [0.6109, 0.083], [-0.4081, 0.292], [-0.1109, -0.2992], [0.5129, -0.0575], [0.1406, -0.4527]])
   ```
2. Для получения столбца из объекта `np.ndarray`, который создаётся функцией `np.array`, круглые скобки не нужны, нужно использовать механизм доступа через индексацию:

   ```
   u = pts2d[:,1]
   v = pts2d[:,2]
   ```
3. Массивы в Python и многих других языках начинаются с нулевого индекса, так что если вы хотите взять первый и второй столбец, нужно использовать индексы 0 и 1:

   ```
   u = pts2d[:,0]
   v = pts2d[:,1]
   ```
4. Так и не понял, к чему относится объявленная, но не завершённая функция `createSystem`

Comment: 1,2,3, поменяла спасибо большое. 4- Это функция с которой я сейчас работаю, она будет возвращать результирующую матрицу.

Comment: @TinaCh В вопросе стоит размещать только то, что непосредственно относится к проблеме.

Answer (score 0):

Можно же в цикле пройтись по массиву и вывести нужный столбец